# Frame Timing in games

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, timing

Ive decided to convert from doing millisecond based timing to frame timing in my rhythm game.  I understand I can check the current frame of the animation to get timing for a button press, but what about when the animation ends and I want a "late buffer" of about 100 milliseconds at the end?  Can I rely on a timer for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to if you limit it to a easily achieviable frame rate. That way you'll know how many frames per second you're running on and thusly how many frames you need to wait.

Or you could do a mixture of both and record the time the last frame of your animation ran, and dont allow it to replay untill the recorded time plus 100 milliseconds has passed.

I think most people use time based timing in games now adays so they can do some other processing if the frame doesnt need to be written